# BeautifulSoup only pulling 1 line when it should be pulling many more

Tags: python, csv, parsing, beautifulsoup

The below code works, but it's only pulling one line of data (Title, Link, Name) when it should be pulling 100+ lines of 'Title, Link, Name'. My guess is something is wrong in the def parse section, but I can't seem to figure it out.

I'd appreciate any help I can get.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://www.blahblah.com'

def get_data(url):
    r = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser') 
    return soup
    
def parse(soup):
    productslist = []
    results = soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'item'})
    results1 = soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'from'})
    for item in results:
        title = item.find('span').text
        link = item.find('a')['href']
    for item1 in results1:
        name = item1.find('span').text          
    product = {
        'Title': title,
        'Link': link,
        'Name': name        
    }
    productslist.append(product)        
    return productslist

def output(productslist):
    productsdf = pd.DataFrame(productslist)
    productsdf.to_csv('output.csv', index=False)
    return
    
soup = get_data(url)    
productslist = parse(soup)  
output(productslist)
```

Comment: Your `for` loops in `parse()` are looping over items and constantly re-assigning the value of `title`, `link` and `name`. Then finally it creates 1 product with the last value from each of them. To fix it you'd need to move the `product{..}` into the for-loop and also the `productslist.append`.

Comment: @MarkM Thank you for the answer, but I'm still having trouble. I understand your explanation, but there are 2 for-loops, both pulling from a different div/class. How would I output the result of those 2 for-loops 'side by side' in a csv as opposed to 'one on top of the other'?

Comment: Assuming the result lists are ordered the same (probably they are) you can iterate over both lists at the same time using Python's `zip()` function, then you only have 1 for-loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
    for item in results:
        title = item.find('span').text
        link = item.find('a')['href']
    for item1 in results1:
        name = item1.find('span').text          
    product = {
        'Title': title,
        'Link': link,
        'Name': name        
    }
```

I think the issues is your assigning Product outside of the for loop so the assignment is only happening once.
Secondly results1, results, item and item1 are not very useful or helpful variables names.
Try names like product_names and product_metadata and then
for metadata in product_metadata
If you want to store the Titles, Links and Names separately you will need to declare variables outside of the scope of the loops, like this

```
    names, title, link = []
    for item in results:
        title = item.find('span').text
        link = item.find('a')['href']
    for item1 in results1:
        name = item1.find('span').text          
    product = {
        'Title': title,
        'Link': link,
        'Name': name        
    }
```

One question how do you know that {name} and {link, title} correspond to the same product on the website?